# Django: Ignore transaction for given update

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a long-running process that should be atomic (Larger update of an application's data). However, during the update, I'd like to let the user know about the progress.

How can I update a model from within the transactioned code, such that it is not part of said transaction?

One potential solution would be to use non-DB storage, such as files, or a second DB connection with the same credentials. Both don't feel like the "right" way to do it...